# How does cv2.findContours() edit the image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, data-science, contour

I have two questions.

1. I am working with openCv and python and I am trying to have an image's contours. I am succesfull at that but when I try to se what is the difference between when I use cv2.drawContorus() functions and directly edit image with cv2.findContours() without sending a copy of original image as the source parameter. I have tried on some images but I couldnt see anything even happenning.
2. I am trying to get the contours of a square I created with paint square tool. But when I try with cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE method, it gives me coordinates of 6 points which none of the combinations from them is suitable for my square. Why does it do like that?

Can someone explain?

Here is my code for both problems:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\fazil\Desktop\12.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.Canny(gray,75,200)
gray = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
cv2.imshow("s",gray)
contours, hiearchy = cv2.findContours(gray,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print(contours[1])
cv2.drawContours(image,contours,1,(45,67,89),5)
cv2.imshow("k",gray)
cv2.imshow("j",image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: can you post the image that you're trying to draw a contour on?

Comment: I do not understand your first question. With respect to question 2, you might use cv2.approxPolyDP() at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga0012a5fdaea70b8a9970165d98722b4c

Comment: Regarding question #1, from the [documentation on `findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0): _Since opencv 3.2 source image is not modified by this function._ It doesn't matter, whether you send a copy or the image directly. There's no in-place modifying of the input (anymore). (Pinging @fmw42 just for information.)

Comment: `@HansHirse` Thanks for the information. I understand that now. I appreciate your comment.

Comment: @HansHirse thank you so much and sorry for seeing late!

Comment: @fmw42 ok but, what does that cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE exactly do then?

Comment: See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga4303f45752694956374734a03c54d5ff.  **compresses horizontal, vertical, and diagonal segments and leaves only their end points. For example, an up-right rectangular contour is encoded with 4 points.**